# Component mounted twice on page refresh when using localstorage for Auth0

Tags: javascript, local-storage, auth0

For some reason, when using cacheLocation='localstorage' for Auth0, a page refresh in our app is causing a call to happen twice...

[image]
Without localstorage it works fine...

[image]

We're using localstorage when running Cypress tests as the page redirect at login doesn't work without it.

The duplication does not happen when first logging in, just on subsequent page refreshes when logged in. Removing the comment in the below code duplicates the call as in the first screenshot...

```
return (
    <Auth0Provider
        domain={process.env...}
        clientId={process.env...}
        redirectUri={
            typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window.location.origin : `http://localhost:3000`
        }
        onRedirectCallback={onRedirectCallback}
        audience={process.env...}
        //cacheLocation='localstorage'
    >
        <UserInfoProvider>
            <PubSubProvider>
                <StackedLayout>
                    <Component {...pageProps} />
                </StackedLayout>
            </PubSubProvider>
        </UserInfoProvider>
    </Auth0Provider>
)
```

Edit: Below is a relevant snippet of the page code...

```
let [searchState, setSearchState] = useState()
const router = useRouter()
const [data, setData] = useState()
const [error, setError] = useState()
const [references, setReferences] = useState({})
const {getAccessTokenSilently} = useAuth0()

useEffect(() => {
const fetchData = async () => {
  setData(null)
  setError(null)

  const accessToken = await getAccessTokenSilently()
  const res = await fetch(
    `${props.apiBaseHref}?${new 
    URLSearchParams(props.query).toString()}`,
    {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
      }
    }
  )

  if (!res.ok) {
    setError('some error')
  } else {
    setData(await (res.json()))
  }
}

setSearchState({ ...props.query })
fetchData()
}, [props.apiBaseHref, props.query, getAccessTokenSilently])
```

Comment: How many times are you using fetch? If it triggers twice, it's presumably because you are indeed running it twice. Can you show us the logic related to this fetch?

Comment: I don't see where you're using localStorage, is that logic somehow triggering a re-render? If it triggers twice it might be that one of the dependencies of useEffect is changing. I see you're passing a function as a dependency `getAccessTokenSilently`. On re-render `getAccessTokenSilently` will have a new reference, that might be triggering the useEffect again. Unless you're using useCallback. Either way, one or more of those three dependencies is changing and that's triggering the useEffect again